# How can I grab the ID inside a nested array/objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

How can I grab the **_id** of **sellerId** inside the **products**? So my backend crash because I change the schema and won't compute the total sum, so right now, how can I grab it.

so this is my data.

```
 {
        "_id": "636656163b470e00d0c44872",
        "userId": {
            "_id": "6366559f3b470e00d0c447e9",
            "studentId": "1234567890"
        },
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": {
                    "_id": "636655f03b470e00d0c447fb",
                    "title": "Shoe Cabinet",
                    "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tua-ecom.appspot.com/o/1667651055293%5Bobject%20File%5D?alt=media&token=608c62f4-915c-47ce-a817-b025bebff06f"
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": {
                    "_id": "636655c53b470e00d0c447eb",
                    "studentId": "1234567891"
                },
                "_id": "636656163b470e00d0c44873"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 100,
        "location": "gym",
        "time": "8 am",
        "status": "pending",
        "tax": 1,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-05T12:24:54.934Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-05T12:24:54.934Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

This is request.

```
router.get("/total/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;


try {
  const income = await Order.aggregate([ 
    {$match: 
      {
        "products.sellerId" : {"$elemMatch": {"_id": id}}
      }
    },
    {$project: {amount: 1}},
  ])
  console.log("Hello")
  res.status(200).json(income);
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
}
```

});

**note,** the id inside the sellerId, is the params I'm using in the router, what I'm trying to do is grab the orders of specific users and compute it.

**EDIT: ADDED SCHEMA**

OrderSchema.js

```
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    products: [
        {
            productId:{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1,
            },
            sellerId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'            
            }
        }
    ],
    amount: {type: Number,required: true},
    location:{type: Object, required:true},
    time: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type:String, default: "pending"},
    tax: {type: Number,}

}, {timestamps: true}
)

export default mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema)
```

Comment: you can check directly `"products.sellerId._id": id`, but make sure if it is stored as objectId type then you have to convert that `"products.sellerId._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`.

Comment: @turivishal my `products.sellerId._id` is already a schema, please check the update info, thanks

Comment: your example data looks different than your schema. I doubt there is some wrong either in the example data or schema.

Comment: I don't know what hapepned, I add this ` const sellerId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` in the request, and then it works? lol. Even though the schema is already objectId

Answer (score 0):

For getting the sellerId `data.products[0].sellerId` should work